# Facebook .. develop a tab have 5 products have users share these individual products to friends wall

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

firstly please forgive me if these is a repeat question, i have looked through the website trying to find similar threads and they didnt exactly answer my question.

my delema is the following, i just wanted to know if it is possible to create a facebook Tab, have for example five products and under this have a button or a feature which allowed users to send this product to a particular friend's WALL with a comment that they can write.

I know there is the share functionality and you can manually tag the post/item i also know of the send functionality which posts a private message.

is there anyway of having this to the wall.?